# Simplest way to know a class's type

Tags: c++, function, inheritance, virtual, rtti

Say I have an Animal class, it would be nice to be able to tell that a pointer is pointing to an Animal object. I know in C++ RTTI and dynamic casting (I think they're the same thing?) is used to find out what type a reference or pointer is. But it's only available through polymorphic inheritance. So if I want a class to be able to tell me what type it is, I have to declare:

```
virtual void dummyfunc(){}
```

And dynamic casting and RTTI would work fine with it.
But I can't for example have a void pointer pointing to something, and be able to tell what type it's pointing to. For example:

```
Animal dog;
Animal* animalPtr = &dog;
typeid(*animalPtr).name();              // RTTI works fine
dynamic_cast<Animal*>(animalPtr);       // Dynamic cast tells me if it's an Animal. Well technically the compiler knows at compile time, but just as example.

void* voidPtr = &dog;
typeid(*voidPtr).name();        // Error, typeid expression must be a complete type
dynamic_cast<Animal*>(voidPtr); // Error, same thing
```

I kind of understand the reasons why the language won't let me do this from void pointers.

The simplest way I know how to make a class tell me what type it is is to just include a virtual dummy function. Is it just me or does this seem to be a hacky way to do it? For example I've thought about having a struct Dummy{} with a virtual function just for the hell of it, and have every object in my program inherit from that. Then any reference to an object would be a reference to Dummy class, and I would be able to tell exactly what type the object was. So for example:

```
Dummy* listOfGodKnowsWhat[1000]; // Assign them to anything
// Loop through, if typeid matches what I want, do the right thing
```

I'm thinking that this is really flexible, but I guess if I want a fully dynamic system then I shouldn't be using C++. Is that the easiest way to be able to tell the type, just add a virtual function? Is this what reflection is? When every object knows what type it is?

Edit: Thanks to latedeveloper for mentioning that I only need a virtual destructor, no need for anything dummy.

Comment: You don't need a "dummy function", you simply need a virtual destructor in the base, which you should have anyway if the base is to be derived from.

Comment: Virtual methods are one of the core fundamental technologies in C++. There's nothing wrong with virtual methods, and in large C++ application, with hunderds of classes, you'll spend quite a bit of time trying to look for a class without a single virtual method.

Comment: What's the problem you're trying to solve with this? This question doesn't look very C++ish.

Comment: @Paul Evans To have a really flexible system for a game engine or simulation. It's as an interest, not work-related.

Comment: *Why* do you want a collection of absolutely everything? Having a collection of a dog, a car, an algorithm, a weather forecast, and a bottle of milk is not very useful. If you have a collection of objects with a common interface, you don't *need* to know their exact types.

Comment: Let's say you have a function that seeks to do operations on animals (notionally, might be represented by a base class `Animal`, and set of classes derived from `Animal`).      What do you expect that function to do if you give it a `void *` which actually points at a `Planet`?   Why would you want to provide such a pointer to the function at all?

Comment: Good points. I'm not sure. Say I had a bag that could contain anything. It could contain anything from a Notepad to Sand. If I had Notepad derived from Item and Air derived from Substance, then I couldn't have both in the same container/array. If they're all derived from a single thing then I could. I agree that this is overly broad though.

Comment: @TitoneMaurice if you're bag is going to be full of of such vague things, then those things will have to have a some sort of reference to a `manager` thing that the sundry bag manager can use to handle them. `thing->manager->manage(thing);`

Comment: As a general performance thing, your program will probably run **much** faster if you store your objects in homogeneous arrays, for instance `std::vector<Animal> animals` and `std::vector<Planet> planets`. Rather than an array of pointers to objects.

Comment: Why would you want objects from my (fictional) program which simulates lifecycle of ants in a nest to be placed in a container within code for your program that implements a text editor?

Comment: @Titone Inheritance should be the last resort when solving a programming problem, not the first.

Comment: All your comments are helpful. I agree that it's really hard to be simulating everything. Thanks for your help, guys.